Quantum Channel with least disturbance for any input and output dimensions
Let $n$ and $m$ be two arbitrary dimensions of the input Hilbert space and output Hilbert space respectively. What is the quantum channel that preserves information as much as possible (i.e. with the least disturbance)?
If $n<m$, then I suppose one could just embed the input to the large space, but mathematically is adding (via direct sum) a null space of dimension $m-n$ a quantum channel?
If $n>m$, then I suppose it's something like a projection, but a projection is not a quantum channel.

How do you define "disturbance" if the dimension of the initial system differs from the dimension of the target system? If $m=n$ then disturbance is often defined as $|\Phi-{\rm id}|_\diamond$ (or similar; see, e.g., Chapter 4.3.3 in Heinosaari & Ziman, "The Mathematical Language of Quantum Theory" (2012)) but this expression does, of course, not make sense when $m\neq n$
